# Where can I find a detailled exposition of the Information theoretic part of BB84?

Tags: cryptography, bb84

I understand the general idea of information reconciliation and advantage distillation, but I can't find any exposition of the algorithm used, unlike the quantum part of the protocol which is well documented and rather easy mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

The actual secure protocol is a little bit different than the original protocol suggested in 84 and referenced to Micael Ben-Or. A good starting point might be this paper - https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-30576-7_21.pdf.